# Copying range of data to table on another workbook

Tags: database, vba, excel, copy

I am trying to make a macro that would Copy range of data from the workbook that is currently open, to a first empty row of table on another workbook which is stored in a network. (it would serve like a database for the data i input on my file)

My choice for excel is because of its data analysis capabilities as the data will have to be monitored and analysed continuously, and kept for records, approx amount of data up to 1 million rows per year.

What kind of code should i be using to achieve this? many hours of search no luck so far, any help appreciated, THANKS!:)

P.S i will be attempting to link approx 10 files with data to that same file(Database) , but as other people might have the database open, will it cause problems with pasting information to the database?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands it's not clear what specific problem you're facing and as such there's not a _correct_ answer we can give you. If you take a shot at writing some code yourself and come to us with your specific problems then we'll be happy to help, but your question as it stands doesn't fit our Q&A format.

Comment: If you will be sharing the file with other users, then Excel is probably not a good choice - it's not clear how you could insert data while someone else has the file open. A better approach might be to store the Data in a database file (such as Access) and query it using Excel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

-edit: Just adding an explanation for anyone who might be skimming solutions. The main thing we do is open both workbooks at the same time and switch between them using `Windows(some_workbook).Activate` where `some_workbook` is the name of the workbook. It can be found using `ActiveWorkbook.Name` Which is usually just the filename with the extension(this is one reason excel doesn't allow you to open workbooks with the same name even if the path is different, since it only uses the file name as a handle it can't differentiate between two physically different files with the same name)

if one workbook isn't open we use `workbook.open Filename:= "PATH_TO_WORKBOOK"` where `PATH_TO_WORKBOOK` is a full path to the workbook you want to open. Also note that it is surrounded by quotes

Besides managing workbooks you probably need to manage sheets (unless you have a simple 1 sheet books) using `sheets(sheet_name).activate` where `sheet_name` is the name of the sheet as a string. It can also be a sheet index(good for iterating through multiple sheets) but generally isn't as reliable since sheet orders can be mixed, or sheets can be added/deleted. Sure users can change sheetnames but that is easier to prevent while still giving them flexibility [see here 'preventing users chaning sheetnames'](http://dedicatedexcel.com/how-to-prevent-users-changing-the-worksheet-name-with-vba/)

You also need to keep track of the two ranges, the one you copy from, and the one you paste to.

Once you get all that done, its just a copy and paste operation

Ok heres your solution. I went to vba and created two modules. The first is FILE_FUNCTIONS

```html
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'this function opens the windows file explorer and allows
'the user to open a file
'PARAMS: N/A
'RETURN: the name of the file if the user picked a file
'        OW returns ""
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Function GuiOpenSpecifiedFile(file_dialog_title, _
    Optional Txt_only As Boolean, Optional CSV_only As Boolean)
'this creates a filedialog object
Set my_fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With my_fd
    'this sets the title
    .Title = file_dialog_title

    'this is so they can only pick one file at a time
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    'this just makes sure they can select anyfile
    .Filters.clear
    
    'adds filters if specified
    If (Not (IsMissing(Txt_only)) And Txt_only) Then
        .Filters.Add "Text", "*.txt"
    End If
    
    If (Not (IsMissing(CSV_only)) And CSV_only) Then
        .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv"
    End If
    
    'this makes the window pop up and saves the selected
    'file to a variable
    file_to_import = .Show
    
End With
       
       
'makes sure they actually chose a file
If (file_to_import <> 0) Then
    
    'this takes the name of the file selected and stores
    'it in a variable
    GuiOpenSpecifiedFile = Trim(my_fd.SelectedItems(1))
    
Else
    'return null value
    GuiOpenSpecifiedFile = ""
End If

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'tells whether or not a specifc file exists
'PARAMS: the full path to the file, or the file name if it
'        is in the same working directory
'RETURN: wthere the file exists
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function FileExists(sFile_path As String) As Boolean
'if file exists DIR returns the file name, or blank otherwise
'if you run DIR("") it returns the workbook title which has a len > 0
'so we also have to check the file name itsel
FileExists = ((Len(Dir(sFile_path)) > 0) And (Len(sFile_path) > 0))

End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'this finds the last row in an excel worksheet
'PARAMS: Opt: sheet_name, the sheet you want to check last row of
'             default is current sheet if not specified
'RETURN: the last row number used in the sheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetLastRow(Optional sheet_name As String)

'gets current sheet name
the_current_sheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'if the user specified a sheet, select it
If (Len(sheet_name) <> 0) Then
    Sheets(sheet_name).Select
End If

'finds the last row
GetLastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'returns to original sheet
Sheets(the_current_sheet).Select
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'this finds the last row in a specific column
'PARAMS: col_to_check, the clumn we want the last row of
'        Opt: sheet_name, the sheet you want to check last row of
'             default is current sheet if not specified
'RETURN: the last row number used in the sheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetLastRowByColumn(col_to_check As String, Optional sheet_name As String)

'gets current sheet name
the_current_sheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'if the user specified a sheet, select it
If (Len(sheet_name) <> 0) Then
    Sheets(sheet_name).Select
End If

'gets last row
GetLastRowByColumn = Range(col_to_check & "65536").End(xlUp).Row

'returns to original sheet
 Sheets(the_current_sheet).Select
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'checks whether or not a sheet exists by looking for its name in the currently
'opened sheets
'PARAMS: sSheetName, as string of the sheetname you want to find
'RETURN: boolean, wehther sheet exists
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function SheetExists(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim bReturn As Boolean

For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then

        bReturn = True
        Exit For

    End If

Next oSheet

SheetExists = bReturn

End Function
```

So copy all those into a module and name it FILE_FUNCTIONS (it saves tons of time to save this module on its own and import it into future projects)

The second module has the actual code. This is where you should make your changes to the sub "Sub CopCellsFromSheetToDataBase" to get your db file and set your columns and ranges

```html
Function OpenWorkbook(spath_to_workbook)
'check if the file exists
If Not (FILE_FUNCTIONS.FileExists(CStr(spath_to_workbook))) Then
    OpenWorkbook = ""
    Exit Function
End If

'surrounds the file name with quotes as required
'spath_to_workbook = Chr(34) & spath_to_workbook & Chr(34)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=spath_to_workbook

'returns the name of the workbook
OpenWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Function


Sub CopyCellsFromSheetToDatabase()
Dim db_sheetname, db_record_col As String

'------------- start configuration -------------------
smy_range_to_copy = "A1:B2"
db_sheetname = CStr("AllRecords")   'cstr must be ppresent
db_record_col = "A"

sdb_filename = FILE_FUNCTIONS.GuiOpenSpecifiedFile("Please select the database file")

'or if you want it to simply be hardcoded you can do that
'sdb_filename = "c:\users\administrator\desktop\my_database.xlsx")
'-------------- end configuration ------------------

'if the user didn't select a file quit sub quietly
If Len(sdb_filename) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.StatusBar = "Copying to database"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'saves the workbook names
curr_workbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
database_workbook = OpenWorkbook(sdb_filename)

'if we opened the file
If (Len(database_workbook) = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Unable to Open workbook " & sdb_filename)
    Exit Sub
End If

'copies range
Windows(curr_workbook).Activate
Range(smy_range_to_copy).Select
Selection.Copy

'switches to db
Windows(database_workbook).Activate

'checks if the db_Sheet exists
If (Not (FILE_FUNCTIONS.SheetExists(db_sheetname))) Then
    MsgBox ("Sheet: " + db_sheetname + vbLf + " not found in: " + sdb_filename)
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    'activates the original workbook (in case you have many others open)
    Windows(curr_workbook).Activate
    
    'restores app settings
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub
End If


'use this if you want only the last row from a particular column and have a sheetname
last_row_of_db = FILE_FUNCTIONS.GetLastRowByColumn(db_record_col, CStr(db_sheetname))

'pastes the values
Range(db_record_col & CStr(last_row_of_db + 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'saves the db and closes it
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close

'activates the original workbook (in case you have many others open)
Windows(curr_workbook).Activate

'returns control to excel
Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The only way I knew how to do this was to open the database workbook, make changes, save, close. As Tim Williams said if many users are using this code simultaneously you could easily run into problems with the file already being in use. This might be something to check into "seeing if a file is in use" http://support.microsoft.com/KB/209189

Comment: This is one extensive answer, very much appreciated it did the job, i ran into a small problem tho, it copied the cells over to row 1535 instead of row #2,ill try to figure out what happened there, either way thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Like I said I save that FILE_FUNCTIONS module (mine version has about 20 more functions I often use) and I just import it (in the vba window where "modules" are right click "import" saves a ton of time.) I only wrote the second module so it wasn't too bad. **back to your issue** @Ejmoska was there something in row 1534? maybe a period? even a space or tab? That might be something to check.

Comment: It appears that row 1534 was the end of the table, so it has pasted the information right below the table. I have deleted the table up to row 2 and problem solved, still no idea why this happened, but it seems to be working ok now , thanks! :)